# Python FTP: parseable directory listing

Tags: python, ftp

I'm using the Python FTP lib for the first time.  My goal is simply to connect to an FTP site, get a directory listing, and then download all files which are newer than a certain date - (e.g. download all files created or modified within the last 5 days, for example)

This turned out to be a bit more complicated than I expected for a few reasons.  Firstly, I've discovered that there is no real "standard" FTP file list format.  Most FTP sites conventionally use the UNIX `ls` format, but this isn't guaranteed.

So, my initial thought was to simply parse the UNIX `ls` format: it's not so bad after all, and it seems most mainstream FTP servers will use it in response to the `LIST` command.

This was easy enough to code with Python's ftplib:

```
import ftplib

def callback(line):
    print(line)

ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftp.example.com")
result = ftp.login(user = "myusername", passwd = "XXXXXXXX")
dirlist = ftp.retrlines("LIST", callback )
```

This works, except the problem is that the date given in the UNIX list format returned by the FTP server I'm dealing with doesn't have a year.  A typical entry is:

```
-rw-rw-r--   1 user user  1505581 Dec  9 21:53 somefile.txt
```

So the problem here is that I'd have to code in extra logic to sort of "guess" if the date refers to the current year or not.  Except really, I'd much rather not code some complex logic like that when it seems so unnecessary - there's no reason the FTP server shouldn't be able to give me the year.

Okay, so after Googling around for some alternative ways to get `LIST` information, I've found that many FTP servers support the `MLST` and `MLSD` command, which apparently provides a directory listing in a "machine-readable" format, i.e. a list format which is much more amenable to automatic processing.  Great.  So, I try the following:

```
dirlist = ftp.sendcmd("MLST")
print(dirlist)
```

This produces a single line response, giving me data about the current working directory, but NOT a list of files.

```
250-Start of list for /
 modify=20151210094445;perm=flcdmpe;type=cdir;unique=808U6EC0051;UNIX.group=1003;UNIX.mode=0775;UNIX.owner=1229; /
250 End of list
```

So this looks great, and easy to parse, and it also has a modify date with the year.  Except it seems the `MLST` command is showing information about the directory itself, rather than a listing of files.

So, I've Googled around and read the [**relevant RFCs**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659#section-7.1), but can't seem to figure out how to get a listing of files in "MLST" format.  It seems the `MLSD` command is what I want, but I get a `425` error when I try that:

```
  File "temp8.py", line 8, in <module>
    dirlist = ftp.sendcmd("MLSD")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/ftplib.py", line 255, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/ftplib.py", line 227, in getresp
    raise error_temp(resp)
ftplib.error_temp: 425 Unable to build data connection: Invalid argument
```

So how can I get a full directory listing in `MLST`/`MLSD` format here?

Comment: You might better use the MDTM command to get the modification time of a single file instead of parsing the directory listing.

Answer (score 0):

There is another module [ftputil](http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/wiki/Documentation) which is built based on ftplib, and has many features emulating os, os.path, shutil. I found it pretty easy to use and robust in related operation. Maybe you could give it a try.

As for your purpose, the introduction codes solves it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this, and see if you can get what you need.

`print(ftp.mlst('directory'))`

I am working on something similar where i need to parse the content of directory and all sub directories within. However the server that I am working with did not allow mlst command, so i accomplished what i need by,

1. parse the main directory content
2. for loop through main directory content
3. Append for loop output to pandas DataFrame.

```
test = pd.Series('ftp.nlst('/target directory/')) 
df_server_content = pd.DataFrame() 
for i in test:
    data_dir = '/target directory/' + i
    server_series = pd.Series(ftp.nlst(data_dir))
    df_server_content = df_server_content.append(server_series)
```